# Can the Lorentz force equation in curved spacetime be derived from the Einstein-Maxwell equations?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, maxwell-equations, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, geodesics

Given the Einstein field equations,

$$R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}R g_{\mu\nu} = \kappa T_{\mu\nu}$$

that imply in particular that $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$, one can show, using the explicit form of $T^{\mu\nu} = T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{particle}}$, that an isolated massive particle travels on a geodesic,

$$\ddot x^\rho + \Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu}\dot x^\mu \dot x^\nu = 0.$$

My question is if someone has ever worked out what the corresponding result is for a charged particle in Einstein-Maxwell theory. I guess the only difference would be the explicit expression for the energy-momentum tensor, which would look something like $T^{\mu\nu} = T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{charged particle}} +  T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{EM}}$, and intuitively it would seem that one should be able to arrive at the Lorentz force equation,

$$\ddot x^\rho + \Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu}\dot x^\mu \dot x^\nu = \frac{q}{m}g^{\rho\mu}F_{\mu\nu}\dot x^\nu,$$

where $F_{\mu\nu}$ is the electromagnetic field tensor.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried Dirac's GR (1975) brochure?

Comment: The stress energy tensor will also include a term which describes the interaction energy between the electromagnetic field and the charged particle, it can't just be decomposed as the stress energy of the particle plus the stress energy of the field.

Comment: @DanielC Thanks! I just had a look and he indeed derives this exact result on page 57.